# Mediawiki add Jquery plugin via ReourceLoader

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, resource-loading

I'm trying to add a JQuery plugin which is not one of core plugins of mediawiki ([twbsPagination](https://github.com/esimakin/twbs-pagination))

The problem is `mw.loader.using` doesn't support URL so I can't pass url of `twbsPagination` to be loaded & `mw.loader.load` doesn't support callback to make me able to run my code after loading the plugin.

How can I load a jquery plugin and use it after the load in mediawiki 1.28 ?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't add to the list of what mw.loader.load or mw.loader.using support, but you can still use $.getScript() without loading anything extra, since jQuery itself comes as part of the default Mediawiki install.  If you have cascading  dependencies, such as a script that makes use of a $.getScript()-loaded plugin, simply nest each level of dependency inside the $.getScript().complete() callbacks just as you would with the callback you'd give mw.loader.using.

As a side note, using $.getScript to load javascript on pages outside of Common.js also allows you to use ES6 in those non-Common.js scripts.  (Mediawiki still doesn't support ES6 on Common.js.)

For a live example, look at lines ~306-335 in https://stratics.com/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.js